# Difficulties with JavaFX key shortcut

Tags: javafx-8

I'm developing an audio player using JavaFX. I m not far from the end but I have some difficulties to manage my keys shortcuts.

As an exemple, on the main window (where the player component is), I want to affect the "right" key to move forward in the song :

```
SoundLooper.getInstance().getPrimaryStage().getScene().setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        ...
        } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
            // RIGHT : Move in media +3s
            player.moveMediaTime(3000);
            event.consume();
        ...
    }
```

This shortcut is directly assigned to the window, to be active regardless of the focused field. This is working well.

Now, I have on this window a spinner field to change volume (the user can write here a value between 0 and 100). I put a filter on it, to accept numerics only :

```
spinnerVolume.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (!event.getCharacter().matches("[1-9]")) {
            event.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

I think doing this, the left and rigth keys will no longer work in this spinner field, but it still working. Now, when I type right key, there are 2 actions :

1. Move cursor in the spinner
2. Move forward in the song

I want the rigth key to go forward regardless of the focused field, but not if this fied can use this key (like a text field, for example). How can I do this ?

Another example. I want all the dialogs in the application to close when user type escape key. I 've got a dialog that contains only an editable combobox, and an "OK" button.
I use the same kind of code to affect this key to my dialog :

```
stage.getScene().setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            validate();
        } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

If the combo box textfield is focused, escape key has no effect (the "handle" method is not called). If I "leave" this field using the TAB key, and then typing escape, the dialog is closing well.
If I replace :

```
else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
```

by

```
else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
```

The popup is closing well typing rigth key, even if the textfield is focused...

I'm sure I'm have miss something, could anyone advice me on the best way to do this ?

Thanks,